# Parsing a complex li tag

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse a HTML file using Jsoup. There are certain text in the HTML that doesn't come under an tags.

```
<li class="inactive"> 
  <span class="status label">inactive</span> 
  <a href="/officers/144662696" class="officer inactive" title="more info on MILLTOWN CORPORATE SERVICES">
     MILLTOWN CORPORATE SERVICES
  </a>
  member, 
  <span class="status label">inactive</span> 
  <a href="/companies/us_wv/193180" class="company inactive revoked_(failure_to_file_annual_report)" title="More Free And Open Company Data On EASTBRIDGE L.L.C. (West Virginia (US), 193180)">
    EASTBRIDGE L.L.C.
   </a> 
   (West Virginia (US), 
   <span class="start_date">25 May 2000</span>-<span class="end_date"> 1 Aug 2002</span>)  
</li>
```

I am able to read all the content in a tag but I am trying to get the values *(West Virginia US)*  and *member*.

Is there a way to get the values outside the classes and inside a `li` tag.

Comment: Not sure about jsoup, but but you can try to get the `innerHTML` of the element.  Look for an api that exposes the html of the element instead of the text value

Comment: I have extracted all other fields using Jsoup. But I will try to get the innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for something like [`Element#ownText`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--).

This only gets the text of the current element and not a combined text of all children.

```
Element listItem = doc.select("li.inactive").first();
System.out.println(listItem.ownText()); // prints "member, (West Virginia (US), -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the previous tags to get the text nodes which are not embedded in any tags. If i get it right, you want to get each text node after each a tag. Try something like :

```
    String html = "<li class=\"inactive\"> \n"
            + "  <span class=\"status label\">inactive</span> \n"
            + "  <a href=\"/officers/144662696\" class=\"officer inactive\" title=\"more info on MILLTOWN CORPORATE SERVICES\">\n"
            + "     MILLTOWN CORPORATE SERVICES\n"
            + "  </a>\n"
            + "  member, \n"
            + "  <span class=\"status label\">inactive</span> \n"
            + "  <a href=\"/companies/us_wv/193180\" class=\"company inactive revoked_(failure_to_file_annual_report)\" title=\"More Free And Open Company Data On EASTBRIDGE L.L.C. (West Virginia (US), 193180)\">\n"
            + "    EASTBRIDGE L.L.C.\n"
            + "   </a> \n"
            + "   (West Virginia (US), \n"
            + "   <span class=\"start_date\">25 May 2000</span>-<span class=\"end_date\"> 1 Aug 2002</span>)  \n"
            + "</li>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Elements links = doc.select("a");
    for(Element e : links){
        System.out.println(e.nextSibling().toString());
    }
```